# Append a specific line BufferedReader java

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader

I want to find a specific line in a BufferedReader which contains, for example, "Result" and store the entire line in a string variable, then print out the string. Is there any ways to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create the BufferedReader.
2. Use [readLine()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) to get a line at a time.
3. Check if it's the line you're looking for, maybe using [contains()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29). If so, store it in a String variable.
4. Close the reader.
5. Print the String.

Comment: +1 for the pseudo code rather than posting working code. For basic questions like this beginners need to learn how to break the problem down into simple steps.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
   String toFind = "Result";
   String line = null;
   StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       if (line.indexOf(toFind) > -1) { // can also use contains()
           buffer.append(line);
           buffer.append('\n');
       }
   }
   // ... Print the buffer like that, or by calling a utility method
   System.out.println(buffer);
} finally {
   reader.close();// wrap in try-catch for any IOE
}
```